# Problems with Data Kind and Singletons in Haskell

Tags: haskell, dependent-type, singleton-type

I'm trying to build a program to regular expression parsing using GADTs and [singletons](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/singletons) library. I'm getting a weird error message:

```
Couldn't match type ‘Integer’ with ‘Nat’
    Expected type: DemoteRep 'KProxy
     Actual type: Nat
     In the first argument of ‘toSing’, namely ‘b_a4Vr’
     In the expression: toSing b_a4Vr :: SomeSing (KProxy :: KProxy Nat)
```

I believe that I'm using all needed extensions in order to compile the code below:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds, KindSignatures, 
   GADTs, TypeFamilies, TemplateHaskell, 
   QuasiQuotes, ScopedTypeVariables #-}

module Lib where

import Data.Proxy
import Data.Singletons.Prelude
import Data.Singletons.TH
import Data.Singletons.TypeLits    


$(singletons [d|
   data RegExp = Sym Nat
               | Eps
               | Cat RegExp RegExp
               | Choice RegExp RegExp|])

type family CHR :: Nat -> Symbol            

data InRegExp (e :: RegExp) (n :: Symbol) where
   InEps :: InRegExp Eps ""
   InChr :: SNat n -> InRegExp (Sym n) (CHR n)
```

Can someone explain why I'm getting this error message? I don't know how to solve it.

Comment: You are facing [this issue](https://github.com/goldfirere/singletons/issues/76).

Comment: Change `data RegExp = Sym Nat | ...` to `data RegExp a = Sym a | ...` if you want `{to/from}Sing` to work for this type.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the comments and [elaborated on in the `singletons` documentation](https://github.com/goldfirere/singletons/blob/cd54a4b3d16db70094544f4c2a99fe3de9ac53cd/README.md), datatypes that support arrows are not supported for promotion or singleton generation. You should be able to work around it by generalizing to `data RegExp a = Sym a | ...`, as mentioned in the comments.

(posting as unowned answer)